# isolating controller tests from models

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mocking, rspec2, stubbing

Is it possible (and reasonable) to write Controller tests and classes before writing the underlying Model classes?  I thought I saw notes on how to do that, but now I can't find the recipe.

For example, consider the following controller:

```
# file: app/controllers/premises_controller.rb
class PremisesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @premise = Premise.new(params[:premise])
    respond_with @premise
  end

end
```

Can I test this controller code before creating the underlying Premise model and premises?  I know the following won't work -- how would you re-write it (if it's possible)?

```
# file: spec/controller/premise_spec.rb
require "spec_helper.rb"

describe PremisesController do
  context 'POST create' do
      it 'should assign a new Premise to @premise' do
        premise = stub_model(Premise)
        Premise.stub(:create) { premise }
        post :create
        assigns(:premise).should == premise
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### update

The more I think about it, the more I'm convinced that I *do* need to define the `Premise` class -- the `PremisesController` code needs to reference it.  So I'll change my question to "is it necessary to create the underlying `premises` database table in order to run the `PremisesController` tests?"

At this point, I don't see a good way around it (without changing the `PremisesController` code, which defeats the point of testing).  For example, the call to `respond_with` calls `@premise.has_errors?` which in turn accesses the database to fetch the column names.  Unless I'm willing to stub methods internal to `ActiveRecord`, I don't see how to avoid a hit to the DB.

But I'd love to be shown otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay - I've made my peace with this: it's not practical to create any meaningful tests unless the database table exists -- too many bits of ActiveRecord depend on having the table defined.

But this doesn't prevent writing test that with a clean separation between the controller and the model.  This is eloquently covered by dchelimsky Himself in [this RSpec issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/78).  The gist of his post:

- Test using an integration test in spec/requests/premise_spec.rb which issues a `get` and verifies the generated json response.
- With a skinny controller method (such as shown in the OP), don't bother writing a controller test.
- Write model tests to verify that the model is emitting the correct json.

By the way, I *really* recommend reading David's post -- he takes you through a step-by-step process, explaining the philosophy and the reasoning behind each step.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code yet, but pretty sure it should work.  You could do this for now:
Just a start, but you could try something like this if you want to, though it is probably bad practice to change your code like this just to pass specs.

```
class PremisesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @premise = premise_until_model_finished params[:premise]
    respond_with @premise
  end

  def premise_until_model_finished premise
    Premise.new premise
  end
end


require "spec_helper.rb"

describe PremisesController do
  context 'when creating a premise' do
    before :each do        
      @my_fake_model = { 
        :some_attribute => 'funk', 
        :some_other_attribute => 'a-delic'
      }
      PremisesController.any_instance.stub( :premise_until_model_finished).and_return(
        @my_fake_model 
      )
      PremisesController.any_instance.should_receive( 
        :premise_until_model_finished
      ).and_return( @my_fake_model )
      post :create
    end

    it 'should create a premise as expected' do
      # your criteria here...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 for the funkadelic reference.  But I agree with you (emphatically) that modifying your production code in order to pass a test negates the point of testing in the first place.